# Image is displaying in inverse order and scaling down to half size cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am drawing image in cocos2d using opengl call but image is displaying in inverse order and scaled down,original size of image is 320*480. i faced same problem previously that time i used to change value of CC_TEXTURE_NPOT_SUPPORT to 1 from 0 in ccConfig file from cocos2d api v1 then it displayed image properly now i am creating new cocos2d project here i am facing same issue, i followed procedure which i used previously but still image is displaying inverse order only what wrong is going i dont know...

screen shot of output

[image: Output image]

Here is my code.....

Code in init method

```
    if( (self=[super init])) {
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
if (originalImage!=nil) {
    originalImage=nil;
}
self.originalImage=[Utilities scaleAndRotateImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"]];

texture2D = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];
NSLog(@"Width %f Height %f",texture2D.contentSize.width,texture2D.contentSize.height);
[self body_init];
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

/* Draw the next frame of animation. */

```
- (void)body_redraw {
int k;
int i, j;
if(mass == NULL) {
NSLog(@"mass is null");
return;
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [texture2D name]);

k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE_X - 1; i++)
{
for (j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE_Y - 1; j++)
{
    GLfloat vertices[]= {
        mass[k].x[0],mass[k].x[1],mass[k].x[2],
        mass[k + 1].x[0],mass[k + 1].x[1],mass[k + 1].x[2],
        mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y + 1].x[0],mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y + 1].x[1],
             mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y + 1].x[2],
        mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y].x[0],mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y].x[1],
         mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y].x[2]
    };
    GLfloat tex[]={
        mass[k].t[0], mass[k].t[1],
        mass[k + 1].t[0], mass[k + 1].t[1],
        mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y + 1].t[0], mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y + 1].t[1],
        mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y].t[0], mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y].t[1]
    };

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tex);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0,4);

    k++;
 }
  k++;
}
}


- (void)body_init {

 GLint width = texture2D.contentSizeInPixels.width;
 GLint height = texture2D.contentSizeInPixels.height;
 int i, j;
 int k;

 if (mass == NULL)
{
mass = (MASS *) malloc(sizeof(MASS)*GRID_SIZE_X*GRID_SIZE_Y);
if (mass == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "body: Can't allocate memory.\n");
    exit(-1);
}
}

k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE_X; i++)
for (j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE_Y; j++)
{
    //this code implements grid on texture2D, gets vertex & side vertex in array
    mass[k].nail = (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == GRID_SIZE_X - 1
                    || j == GRID_SIZE_Y - 1);//value is 0/1

    mass[k].x[0] = i/(GRID_SIZE_X - 1.0)*width;
    //            NSLog(@"mass[%d].x[0]:: %f",k,mass[k].x[0]);

    mass[k].x[1] = j/(GRID_SIZE_Y - 1.0)*height;
    //            NSLog(@"mass[%d].x[1]:: %f",k,mass[k].x[1]);

    mass[k].x[2] = -(CLIP_FAR - CLIP_NEAR)/4.0;
    //            NSLog(@"mass[%d].x[2]:: %f",k,mass[k].x[2]);

    mass[k].v[0] = 0.0;
    mass[k].v[1] = 0.0;
    mass[k].v[2] = 0.0;

    mass[k].t[0] = i/(GRID_SIZE_X - 1.0);
    mass[k].t[1] = j/(GRID_SIZE_Y - 1.0);

    k++;
  }
}

- (void)draw {

glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glColor4ub(224,224,244,200);

[self body_redraw];

glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

}

Comment: i am expecting anyone should look at this issue

Comment: is'nt opengl always load texture upside down...?

Comment: how do i make upside up

Answer (score 0):

If it is cocos2d game then you can use these calls to reverse image and scale down.

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Filename.png"];
[parent addChild:sprite];
[sprite setPosition: ccp( p.x, p.y)];

sprite.flipY = true;
sprite.scale = 1.0f;
```